# Windows 7 blue screens but Ubuntu14.04 still boots

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

I have been running a dual boot Windows 7 Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron N5040 for months. The Windows 7 configured some updates yesterday after which chkdsk reported a lot of filesystem corrruption. Since then  I haven't been able to boot Windows even to safe-mode (a blue screen flashes then disappears). So far a repair disk hasn't helped either. But Ubuntu still boots. I can't post the gparted image but /dev/sda3 shows 581 GB and /host/Windows still seems intact.

Comment: did you try to install linux grub again? I think it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perform chkdsk on needed partitions with /F /R /X parameters from repair disk.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like your window partition is corrupted, I would just hope you had backed up anything important, format the windows partition and reinstall windows

Comment: Whoa, why not try to fix it first?

Comment: if he has access to the files he needs from inside his ubuntu install, then the quickest and easiest solution in this case sounds to me like it would be reformat, why fix if he can get the files?

Comment: 1. Because filesystem is damaged and files can be corrupted even if they appear fine in Ubuntu, 2. Because running `chkdsk /r` is simplier than reinstalling Windows with all your programs and restoring backups.

Comment: no you're right, I guess what I meant was IF chkdsk /r doesn't do it, then reformat...